# How to write a typescript interface for two parameter needed but one excludes the other

Tags: javascript, typescript

I used this method but it also accepts both interfaces.
I need one to exclude the other.

```
export interface C extends A {
    single: boolean;
}

export interface B extends A {
    couple: boolean;
}

export interface A {
    others: string;
}

export type A = B | C;
```

Those are my test, in the third case i need that ts give me error:

```
\\ OK
const test1: A = {
    single: true,
    others: ''
}

\\ OK
const test2: A = {
    couple: true,
    others: ''
}

\\ OK BUT I DONT WANT THIS!!
const test3: A = {
    single: true,
    couple: true,
    others: ''
}
```

Comment: This does not compile because the identifier `A` is used for both the interface and the union type. Apart from that there are syntax errors on the semicolons.

Comment: Define `A` as `export type A = StrictUnion<B | C>` and it will work, `StrictUnion` in the duplicate (would not mind if you upvote it ;)) Let me know if you have any issues with it, but i tested your example and it works

Comment: Seems it's fixed in v3.5: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-5.html#improved-excess-property-checks-in-union-types